# Modifying python code to get imaginary solutions of numerical integration method

Tags: integration, definition

I stumbled upon this code to integrate functions using the numerical method Gauss Kronrod which I have been recommended for the functions I am integrating. So far in all the trials I have used I have found that it works to a reasonably well accuracy. However it completely omits the imaginary parts of the solution.

Here is the example for integrating ln(x) from -5 to 0, the real part is correct but there is no imaginary part:

```
# let's test integrazi for ln(x) from -1 to 2
import scipy
import cmath
from scipy import array


def quad_routine(func, a, b, x_list, w_list):
    c_1 = (b-a)/2.0
    c_2 = (b+a)/2.0
    eval_points = map(lambda x: c_1*x+c_2, x_list)
    func_evals = map(func, eval_points)
    return c_1 * sum(array(func_evals) * array(w_list))

def quad_kronrod_15(func, a, b):
    x_kr = [-0.991455371120813,-0.949107912342759, -0.864864423359769, -0.741531185599394, -0.586087235467691,-0.405845151377397, -0.207784955007898, 0.0, 0.207784955007898,0.405845151377397, 0.586087235467691, 0.741531185599394, 0.864864423359769, 0.949107912342759, 0.991455371120813]
    w_kr = [0.022935322010529, 0.063092092629979, 0.104790010322250, 0.140653259715525, 0.169004726639267, 0.190350578064785, 0.204432940075298, 0.209482141084728, 0.204432940075298, 0.190350578064785, 0.169004726639267, 0.140653259715525,  0.104790010322250, 0.063092092629979, 0.022935322010529]
    return quad_routine(func,a,b,x_kr, w_kr)

class Memoize(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.eval_points = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args not in self.eval_points:
            self.eval_points[args] = self.func(*args)
        return self.eval_points[args]

def quadt(func,a,b):
    func = Memoize(func) #  Memoize function to skip repeated function calls.
    k15 = quad_kronrod_15(func,a,b)
    # I don't have much faith in this error estimate taken from wikipedia
    # without incorporating how it should scale with changing limits
    return k15

def INTEGRATEME(func, **kwargs):       # INTEGRATEZI short for Integrating from zero to infinity
    def real_func(x):
        return scipy.real(func(x))
    integral = quadt(real_func, -5.0, 0)  # lower limit of integral is -5 and upper limit is 0.
    return (integral)


print INTEGRATEME( lambda kp: cmath.log(kp)) # integrating ln(x) from -5 to 0
```

Here is the output:

```
%run "c:\users\envy14~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpnsvrem.py"
3.05565292766
```

## the true solution is 3.04719 + 15.708i